# ITIN-Issue-IRS requesting for original passport/Certified copies

Tags: united-states, taxes, irs, itin

I have submitted my wife's ITIN application (W7) along with 2012 federal tax return copy at the local tax office on 14th March 2013 in NJ.
The person at the tax office did verified my wife's Passport, W7 form and he returned few last papers from my TAX returns with a stamp on it stating "RECEIVED WITH REMITTANCE" and finally told us it will take 8 weeks to get the ITIN and Refund if my Refund is approved.

Again on April 15th I received a notice form IRS requesting original passport or certified copies from the authority who issued the passport even though IRS official has verified the original passport.
I chose the second option and certified the passport copies  from Indian embassy and did an express mail to IRS

did anyone has any issues even after sending the certified copies

Please share.

Comment: This question is close enough to [this one](http://money.stackexchange.com/q/21501/5760) asked about two weeks ago to be considered a duplicate. Even  the OP names are similar! The latter has not received an answer as yet, though the OP did promise to write an answer after finding out what the IRS would accept. I recommend this one be merged with the other question, and both OPs encouraged to tell us what happened.